# How can I simplify this code in python?

Tags: python

The task is to get all the multiples of 3 below 100, and then add them together.

```
num1 = 0
l = []
while num1 < 100:
    num1 = num1 + 3
    l.append(num1)
# I used this to delete the last element in the list which is 102,
del l[-1]
print l
# sum of all the numbers in l
b = sum(l)
print b
```

Comment: How my question is not clear enough?, I already received answers from several users and it was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
total = 0
for i in range(0,100, 3):
    total += i
print(total)
```

Alternative, one-liner:

```
answer = sum(range(0, 100, 3))
```

Comment: Oh, you've beaten me by several seconds... This is what happens when you have slow Internet connection :D

Comment: Shouldn't range start at 3? As in, `range(3, 100, 3)`? That list contains 0, and 0 is not a multiple of 3. The sum will be correct, of course, but it is the principle of the thing...

Comment: Interesting, I always though 0 was a multiple of 3 because 0%3 is 0

Comment: Depends on what definition you want to use. Generally (recalling my University years), one is only concerned with positive integer multiples. In practical terms the result is the same, but starting the range at 0 in this case is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I do not know how my question has downvotes, I am really new to programming and I was just looking for help, is that because my question is not valid?

Comment: @Jesus: it's a valid question. I think it got downvotes (not from me) because it is a "how do I make my code better?" question, which typically belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jesus I upvoted it, it's a valid question, you even provided your attempt, I can't see reasonable reasons to downvote it, it could be fitted into "too broad" questions btw. Try not to be intimidated by it =)
yep, inspectorG4dget is right, if your code works, it usually belongs into codereview website.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
sum(range(0, 100, 3))
```

Answer (score 3):

By Gaussian sum,

```
total = 3 * (100 // 3) * (100 // 3 + 1) // 2
```

Comment: Ok, so `sum(range(3, 100, 3))` is not the *coolest* afterall.